# Serving protected images with Nginx silently

Tags: php, nginx

My folder `uploaded_images` contains jpeg images (inside and in subdirectories) and I need to authenticate users to check if they can see the picture. This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['p'];
if($user_can_see_this_files){
   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
   header('X-Accel-Redirect: /uploaded_images/'.$file);
}else{
   header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
}
?>
```

I can simply show the images using a link like following if I make the directory `uploaded_images` as `internal` in the nginx configuration file:

```
http://example.com/view.php?p=example.jpg
```

Or

```
http://example.com/view.php?p=subfolder/example.jpg
```

But I want to show the images using the usual link like following:

```
http://example.com/uploaded_images/example.jpg
```

Or in the case of the second previous example :

```
http://example.com/uploaded_images/subfolder/example.jpg
```

How can I do it with the nginx configuration file?

Comment: With recent nginx you could use http://nginx.org/r/auth_request module.

Comment: @AlexeyTen how can I use it in my case?

Comment: Have you read doc on auth_request? It's exactly what you need. Have you tried to use it somehow?

Comment: Alexey is absolutely right, you can even cache the response from authentication service to avoid performance issues.

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes but I don't understand how to use it in my case. To be precise I don't understand how to implement this module, what response must give my php script to authorize nginx to serving the image? Can you give me a complete example with PHP code (pseudocode is fine, like mine) and the nginx configuration please?

Comment: > If the subrequest returns a 2xx response code, the access is allowed. If it returns 401 or 403, the access is denied with the corresponding error code.

Comment: @AlexeyTen perfect, thank you. Where I have to specify in nginx configuration file which is the php script that deals with authorization? Maybe proxy_pass?

Comment: There is an example on that page.

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes I'm exactly talking about it, is proxy_pass the right place where I must specify which is the php script that deals with authorization?

Comment: Yes, it is the right place. I tested it. Thank you @AlexeyTen for the suggestion of this module.